# cpack conditonal behaviour based on generator

Tags: cmake, rpmbuild, cpack

I have a build which is currently set up with steps as follows:

```
cmake
make
cpack -G TGZ
cpack -G RPM
```

I now have a problem in that there are files I wish to include in the RPM but not the tarball. Is there a way to make the install command conditional according to the generator used?

The simple and obvious way is wrong:

```
if (NOT ${PACKAGE_TYPE} STREQUAL "TGZ")
   message("HELLO ${PACKAGE_TYPE}")
   install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foobar DESTINATION "/usr/lib" COMPONENT core RENAME "/usr/lib/only-install-me-for-RPM")
endif()
```

I believe it is wrong because the configure stage (running cmake) evaluates the conditional but cpack does not.
I do not want two builds as the install stage is the only part different. I do want more than one kind of installation package.

### Background

Why do I want to do such an odd thing? I can think of other legitimate reasons but in this case it is because of the introduction of [/usr/lib/.build-id](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeatureBuildId).
It is not possible to disable this behaviour from cmake (though it is possible in the .spec file see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1724153)

In RHEL8 rpmbuild installs files (actually links) in /usr/lib/.build-id which I have not specificed myself.
In order to persuade cmake to make /usr/lib relocatable I have to install a dummy file in /usr/lib - see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20691

This is not necessary for the tarball.

Comment: It turns out I can solve my problem using set(CPACK_RPM_SPEC_MORE_DEFINE "%define _build_id_links none") to disable .build-id in the RPM spec but the question of how to do it the other way still stands.

Comment: Not an answer, because I don't know cmake, but traditionally you'd need to have additional "Source" lines in the specfile, _e.g._ `Source1: myfile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Currently used CPack generator can be retrieved from [CPACK_GENERATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_GENERATOR) variable. But this meaning works only inside a script specified with [CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE) variable. Inside `CMakeLists.txt` the variable `CPACK_GENERATOR` has other meaning.

Because `install` command can only be issued in `CMakeLists.txt`, this command cannot be made conditional (based on CPack generator). But you may assign a `COMPONENT` for this installation. This component can be excluded from the components list later.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Assign 'core_special' COMPONENT for installation
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foobar DESTINATION "/usr/lib" COMPONENT core_special RENAME "/usr/lib/only-install-me-for-RPM")

# ...

# Set config script for CPack. 
set(CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cpack_project_config.cmake")
```

**cpack_project_config.cmake**:

```
# Exclude component "core_special" for all CPack generators except TGZ.
if (NOT CPACK_GENERATOR STREQUAL "TGZ")
  list(REMOVE_ITEM CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL "core_special")
endif()

# Need to set 'CMAKE_<GENERATOR>_COMPONENT_INSTALL' to ON, otherwise CPack ignores CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL variable
set(CPACK_ARCHIVE_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)

# E.g create single archive/package from all components
# (other values - "IGNORE", "ONE_PER_GROUP" - will also work)
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_GROUPING "ALL_COMPONENTS_IN_ONE")
```

Comment: That looks plausible but painful (in the way cmake usually is). I'm not sure that will play well if you are already using a component install. The extra file will be in a separate optional component rather than the same file won't it? I think you are confirming that what I wanted to do isn't possible?

Comment: "The extra file will be in a separate optional component rather than the same file won't it?" - If you don't use per-component installation, then `CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL` describes all components which come into the resulted file. Extra files (which doesn't fit into the listed components) will go nowhere. As far as I understand, this is exactly what do you want.

Comment: Unfortunately I do use per-component installation but your solution looks good for the single component case.

Comment: I just tested my approach in different modifications. Once [CMAKE_<GENERATOR>_COMPONENT_INSTALL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/CPackComponent.html#variable:CPACK_%3CGENNAME%3E_COMPONENT_INSTALL) variable is set to ON, CPack follows setting `CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL` variable. That is, removed component neither appears in the ALL_COMPONENTS_IN_ONE package nor generates per-component package in "IGNORE" case. (In case of ONE_PER_GROUP packages are created based on *groups* list. If neither group contains removed component, then no files will be generated for this component too.)